# c language - system() function not working when I set program auto run with supervisor

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to make slideshow program in Linux. My problem is when I set my program autorun with a supervisor, mplayer works and runs videos but eog or feh not working to show images. But it's working when I call my program from terminal and shows videos and images.

Here is my code for system() calls.

```
if(!strcmp(ext,".JPG") || !strcmp(ext,".jpg") || !strcmp(ext, ".gif") || !strcmp(ext,".png") || !strcmp(ext, ".PNG") || !strcmp(ext, ".GIF"))
{
  char command[1000];
  snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "eog -f %s%s&", FILE_PATH, liste[counter]);
  if(childpid != 0)
  {
    char kill_command[100];
    snprintf(kill_command, sizeof(kill_command), "kill %d", childpid);
    system(kill_command);
    childpid=0;
  }
  system(command);
  sleep(5);
  childpid = getpid() + 2;
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
else if (!strcmp(ext,".mov") || !strcmp(ext, ".mp4") || !strcmp(ext, ".avi") || !strcmp(ext,".wmv"))
{
  if(childpid != 0)
  {
    char kill_command[100];
    snprintf(kill_command, sizeof(kill_command), "kill %d", childpid);
    system(kill_command);
    childpid=0;
  }
  char command[1000];
  snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "omxplayer -o hdmi -b %s%s", FILE_PATH, liste[counter]);
  system(command);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: When you run a program from the terminal it will inherit your personal settings, most notably the `PATH` and `DISPLAY`environment variables. These environment variables are probably  different when supervisor tries to run the programs.

Comment: `childpid = getpid() + 2` what?!?!  Please don't do this, ever. Learn about `fork` and `exec`.

Comment: I've thought that but my path is static so it is not from path but i am not sure about displaying settings. I think mplayer works beause of "-o hdmi" parameter. It sends videos to hdmi but i couldn't find any similar setting for eog or feh. I've tried "eog -f --display=:0 path" or "DISPLAY=:0.0 eog -f path" but didn't work.

Comment: what will happen if the extension is `Jpg`, `PNG` or `GIF`? why don't use `stricmp`?

Answer (score 0):

Read [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html). It forks some `/bin/sh -c`, so read [sh(1p)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sh.1p.html) then [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html). A command is searched using [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) by [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) or its internal shell equivalent.

So either `eog` is not found in your `$PATH` or in the default one, or it cannot display e.g. because of some missing `$DISPLAY` (e.g. needed for some [XOpenDisplay(3)](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/opening.html) indirectly called by `eog`). Perhaps you could replace `eog` by your shell script (redirecting its stderr before running `eog`).

You need to learn a lot more, so read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (freely downloadable). For instance `childpid = getpid() + 2;` (or any arithmetic on `pid_t`) is total non-sense. The [fork system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) is essential, but difficult, to understand. See at least [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), and perhaps [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)

You could use a debugger to debug your program. With care `gdb` can handle `fork`s.

BTW, using `kill` thru [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) as a command is a mistake. You want the [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) system call, but you probably don't need it. See also [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).